# What are the Godot equivalent to these Unity types and Functions for graphics processing?

Tags: unity, shaders, rendering, godot, compute-shader

Here are some unity types in this script: https://github.com/aras-p/UnityGaussianSplatting/blob/main/package/Runtime/GaussianSplatRenderer.cs

which I am trying to convert to Godot:

```
ComputeShader //For functions like GetKernelThreadGroupSizes and Dispatch
GraphicsBuffer //For use with the commandbuffer
CommandBuffer //For all sorts of functions from DrawProcedural to ReleaseTemporaryRT
Hash128 //For knowing when to dispose of resources
ProfilerMarker //For profiling
ProfilerCategory //For profiling
MeshTopology //For triangles for drawing
GraphicsFormat //For R16G16B16A16_SFloat
FilterMode //For Point
RTClearFlags //For Color
BuiltInRenderTextureType //For CurrentActive
Graphics //For DrawProcedural
Bounds //For DrawProcedural
```

Ultimately the Godot compute shaders are described here https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/shaders/compute_shaders.html but I don't know how to translate this into that. If you could tell me how to translate each of these individual types or just change my entire approach for Godot, either of these would be very helpful. Thanks.